# After Insert and After Update Trigger Handler delay in UI

Tags: apex, trigger

I am new to APEX and I created two Trigger Handlers. They are identical but for different objects. This is for SF Billing Credit and Debits.

Everything works, but one is delayed and the other shows changes immediately. It is when I go to change the status to Posted. My Debits reflect posted immediately while I have to wait for the Credit Notes to have that behavior. Any thoughts on what would cause the UI delay and can I fix it with code?

```
public class CreditNoteTriggerHandler extends TriggerHandler{  

/* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  


* Created: 2019  

* Purpose: To automatically create credit note lines when a credit note line is created


* Change Log:  

* Moved Adjustment Type 'Add Correct Payment' to Product AR Clearing and allowed for updates to the 
Start and End Date on Credit Lines based on Credit Note Date- Sprint 188 STT - Update Adjustment Types Related to Misapplied Payments   

*   

*  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  


*/  

    //overrides  

    protected override void afterInsert() {  

        System.debug('CreditNoteTriggerHandler afterInsert()');  

        insertCreditNoteLine();  


    }  

    protected override void afterUpdate() {  


        System.debug('CreditNoteTriggerHandler afterUpdate()');  


        updateCreditNoteLine();}  



    @TestVisible  



    private void insertCreditNoteLine(){  

        //line.blng__LegalEntity__c = d.blng__Account__r.ZVP_Franchise__r.ZVP_Legal_Entity__r.Id;
        Map<id,blng__creditNote__c> creditnotemap = (Map<id,blng__creditNote__c>)Trigger.newmap;

        List<blng__creditNote__c> creditNotes = new List<blng__creditNote__c>([Select Id, blng__Account__r.ZVP_Franchise__r.ZVP_Legal_Entity__r.Id, blng__CreditNoteDate__c, 
                                                                               ZVP_Amount__c, blng__CreditNoteSourceAction__c, ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c  
                                                                               FROM blng__creditNote__c WHERE Id in: creditnotemap.keyset()]);

        //List<blng__creditNote__c> creditNotes = (List<blng__creditNote__c>)Trigger.new;

        List<blng__CreditNoteLine__c> creditNoteLinesToInsert = new List<blng__CreditNoteLine__c>(); 

        //Looping through credit notes 
        for(blng__CreditNote__c c : creditNotes){  

        //Determining what the Credit Note Line Product should be based on the Credit Note adjustment type
        if(c.blng__CreditNoteSourceAction__c == 'Manual'){  


                Valpak__c vpc = Valpak__c.getOrgDefaults();




                //String discountstring = vpc.ZVP_Discounts_Returns_Allowances__c;  



                //Id discountid = id.valueOf(discountstring);  



                blng__CreditNoteLine__c line = new blng__CreditNoteLine__c();  

                line.blng__CreditNote__c = c.Id;   

                line.blng__StartDate__c = c.blng__CreditNoteDate__c;   

                line.blng__EndDate__c = c.blng__CreditNoteDate__c;   


                System.debug(c.blng__Account__r.ZVP_Franchise__r.ZVP_Legal_Entity__r.Id);
                line.blng__LegalEntity__c = c.blng__Account__r.ZVP_Franchise__r.ZVP_Legal_Entity__r.Id;  

                line.blng__Subtotal__c = c.ZVP_Amount__c;  



               if(c.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'NSF Add Payment'||
                 c.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'Add Correct Payment'){  

                   line.blng__Product__c = id.valueOf(vpc.ZVP_Billing_AR_Clearing__c);   


               }Else if(c.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'Bad Debt Write-Off'){  

                    line.blng__Product__c = id.valueOf(vpc.ZVP_Allow_for_Doubtful_Accounts_PC_Req__c);   

               }Else if (c.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'Exchange Rate - Reduce Amount Received'||  

                     c.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'Intercompany Credit'){  

                     line.blng__Product__c = id.valueOf(vpc.ZVP_Accrued_Intermarket_Fees_Payable__c);   

               }Else if (c.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'Misc Credit'||  

                        //Moved to a different Product on 8/15/19 c.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'Add Correct Payment'||  

                        c.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'Go-Live Balance Reduction'||     

                        c.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'Finance Charge (CR)'||   

                        c.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'VBC Credit'){  

                            line.blng__Product__c = id.valueOf(vpc.ZVP_Clearing_Account_Other__c); 

               }Else if(c.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'Barter/Direct Trade'){  

                            line.blng__Product__c = id.valueOf(vpc.ZVP_Trade_Barter_Expense__c);   

               }Else if(c.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'Coupon/Discount'||  

                        c.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'Sales Price Decrease'||  

                        c.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'Refunds - Invoice'){  

                                line.blng__Product__c = id.valueOf(vpc.ZVP_Discounts_Returns_Allowances__c);   

               }Else if(c.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'Collection Agency Fee Removed'){  

                                line.blng__Product__c = id.valueOf(vpc.ZVP_Collection_Fees__c); //line.blng__Subtotal__c = c.ZVP_Amount__c;  

               }Else if (c.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'Sales Tax Decrease'){  

                                line.blng__Product__c = id.valueOf(vpc.ZVP_Sales_Tax__c); //line.blng__Subtotal__c = c.ZVP_Amount__c;  

               }  


            //Lines that should be added
            creditNoteLinesToInsert.add(line);  


                                }//if manual  

         }//end for loop  

        //If there is more than one credit note line then insert credit note lines
        if(creditNoteLinesToInsert.size() > 0) {  

            System.debug('creditNoteLinesToInsert: ' + creditNoteLinesToInsert);  

            insert creditNoteLinesToInsert;  

        } //End of if there are credit note lines to insert 

    }




    @TestVisible  



    private void updateCreditNoteLine(){  


    //Mapping the Credit Notes with their Ids
    Map < Id,  blng__CreditNote__c > mapCreditNote = new Map < Id, blng__CreditNote__c >();  


    //Creating an empty list of Credit Note Lines
    List<blng__CreditNoteLine__c> listCreditNoteLines = new List<blng__CreditNoteLine__c>();  


    Valpak__c vpc = Valpak__c.getOrgDefaults();
        //Looping through the Credit Notes that have an update
        for(blng__CreditNote__c c : (List<blng__CreditNote__c>) trigger.new){  



        mapCreditNote.put(c.Id, c);  



    //List<blng__creditNote__c> creditNotes = (List<blng__CreditNote__c>)Trigger.new; 



    //Valpak__c vpc = Valpak__c.getOrgDefaults(); 



    //blng__CreditNote__c cn; 



    //(blng__CreditNote__c cn : (List<blng__CreditNote__c>) trigger.new)  



    //(blng__CreditNote__c cn : creditNotes) 



     //mapCreditNote.put(c.Id, c);  

        }//Close for loop

    listCreditNoteLines = [ SELECT     blng__CreditNoteLineDate__c, blng__Subtotal__c, blng__CreditNote__c, 
                           blng__Product__c FROM blng__CreditNoteLine__c WHERE blng__CreditNote__c IN : mapCreditNote.keySet() ];  


    //If the Credit Note Lines are greater than Zero update the Credit Note Line Date, Amount, and Product based on the Credit Note
    if ( listCreditNoteLines.size() > 0 ) {  



        for ( blng__CreditNoteLine__c cnl : listCreditNoteLines ) {  

            blng__CreditNote__c cn = mapCreditNote.get(cnl.blng__CreditNote__c);

            cnl.blng__CreditNoteLineDate__c = cn.blng__CreditNoteDate__c;  


            cnl.blng__Subtotal__c = cn.ZVP_Amount__c; 

            cnl.blng__StartDate__c = cn.blng__CreditNoteDate__c;   

            cnl.blng__EndDate__c = cn.blng__CreditNoteDate__c;   


                if(cn.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'NSF Add Payment'||

                  cn.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'Add Correct Payment'){  

                   cnl.blng__Product__c = id.valueOf(vpc.ZVP_Billing_AR_Clearing__c);  

                  }Else if(cn.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'Bad Debt Write-Off'){  

                    cnl.blng__Product__c = id.valueOf(vpc.ZVP_Allow_for_Doubtful_Accounts_PC_Req__c);   

                  }Else if (cn.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'Exchange Rate - Reduce Amount Received'||  

                     cn.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'Intercompany Credit'){  

                     cnl.blng__Product__c = id.valueOf(vpc.ZVP_Accrued_Intermarket_Fees_Payable__c);   

               }Else if (cn.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'Misc Credit'||  

                        // Moved to Product AR Clearing cn.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'Add Correct Payment'||  

                        cn.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'Go-Live Balance Reduction'||     

                        cn.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'Finance Charge (CR)'||   

                        cn.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'VBC Credit'){  

                            cnl.blng__Product__c = id.valueOf(vpc.ZVP_Clearing_Account_Other__c); 

               }Else if(cn.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'Barter/Direct Trade'){  

                            cnl.blng__Product__c = id.valueOf(vpc.ZVP_Trade_Barter_Expense__c);   

               }Else if(cn.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'Coupon/Discount'||  

                        cn.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'Sales Price Decrease'||  

                        cn.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'Refunds - Invoice'){  

                                cnl.blng__Product__c = id.valueOf(vpc.ZVP_Discounts_Returns_Allowances__c);   

               }Else if(cn.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'Collection Agency Fee Removed'){  

                                cnl.blng__Product__c = id.valueOf(vpc.ZVP_Collection_Fees__c); //line.blng__Subtotal__c = c.ZVP_Amount__c;  

               }Else if (cn.ZVP_Credit_Adjustment_Type__c == 'Sales Tax Decrease'){  

                                cnl.blng__Product__c = id.valueOf(vpc.ZVP_Sales_Tax__c); //line.blng__Subtotal__c = c.ZVP_Amount__c;  

               }  


                } 

            } //If list of credit note lines is greater than zero update the Credit Note Lines

  update listCreditNoteLines;  
    }
}
```

Comment: The trigger you're showing here has no reference to a Posted status. It sounds like you may have a parent object trigger that updates these records? In any case, more detail will help - what is the UI? Is it custom, standard, Lightning, Visualforce? Are you looking at a related list? What sequence of steps takes place?

Comment: Hi David. So we use Salesforce Billing which is a managed package meaning their code is hidden. Both the Debit and Credit Note is standard Salesforce Billing and you can normally click the UI to change the status to Posted.                                                             When we select Posted on the Debit note (Normal update to the record) it saves and reflects posted. This used to happen for Credit Notes too until I created code to handle updates. My code for both the Debit note and Credit note trigger handlers are the same. My Triggers are the same yet I get different behavior.